# split strings into nested array by matching sub string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to split a string into a nested array something like [this](http://pastebin.com/g8CL5Xb2). Small subset of the [actual data](http://pastebin.com/BLPVfvBj)

- There is no fixed size, code could be `aaa100` and `bbbbbbbb100`
- No fixed char to split on

A similar problem is with converting [file path to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079397/how-would-i-split-multiple-strings-into-a-deep-nested-array) but I dont have anything like `/` to split on.

#### Use case:

Product import with a few thousand products. Each product code is made up with something like the following:

```
xxx product type
yyy size
zzz colour
```

So you have codes like `xxxx`, `xxxxyy`, `xxxxzz` or `xxxxyyzz`.

```
AAA100B // product type AAA with size 100 and colour blue
AAA200B // product type AAA with size 200 and colour blue
AAA100G // product type AAA with size 100 and colour green
BBB100B // product type BBB with size 100 and colour blue
```

Some do not have colour, others don't have size. Possible that some will not have 'matches' and just be a lone code.

#### Edit

The last char (or two) is normally a colour. Colours can be any of the following. (Colour code will never anywhere except the end of the string)

```
BK, GY
B, G, O, P, R, S
```

numbers are assumed to be the size, if the number is in the form `00-00` its lenght/width, else its a single size `00`

#### Edit

Rough start to the problem, virtually there (expand and merge are part of the framework so just hacked them in there) http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wp19g2

Comment: There has to be some pattern to the input .. is it always "Letters""Numbers""Letters"?

Comment: I linked a sample of actual data http://pastebin.com/BLPVfvBj. Only real pattern is 'product-type' - 'size' - 'colour', but colour and size are not always there. There is also no separator between them always

Comment: Well there has to be a way to know when product-type ends and size (or color) begins

Comment: generally the size would be numeric while the rest is alpha. The colours seem to always be the last char (or two in some cases like BK for black as B is blue).

Comment: If you're saying that product-type can be followed immediately by color and that both are alpha and there is no pattern to color, then this is kind of impossible

Comment: The key I think, is using the other product codes for reference. xxxxB and xxxxR is the same product type but different colours. Not entirely impossible.

Comment: I don't think that helps. If you have two codes ABCDE and ABCDF, are they both product ABC with colors DE and DF, or product ABCD with colors E and F?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that there will be at least one code for each product type with a size? Then you could use them as the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I guess the obvious (yet somewhat inefficient) way would be to take your code string, loop through the letters till you reach a number (recording all the letters up to that point as your product type), when you reach a number record that value and every number after it till you reach a letter again, and begin recording the color. This, of course, assumes that the color and product type does not include numbers!

```
$product_size = ""; $product_type = ""; $product_color = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen ( $code ); $i++ ) {
     if ( !is_numeric ( $code [ $i ] ) ) { 
          if ( $product_size == "" ) $product_type .= $code [ $i ];
          else $product_color .= $code [ $i ]
     } else $product_size .= $code [ $i ];
}
```

Its a good design choice to have a separator though. One problem with my solution is that if there is no product size then it will never record a color.

Comment: This doesn't work for the codes with no size between the type and color.

Comment: Yup. I'm not sure how one can overcome that hurdle without a separator or a good idea at how we can differentiate between the blocks.

Comment: That's the problem. Until the OP provides enough information to disambiguate, there's not much point in posting answers.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a choice in the separator matter. Just using what I have got. I have added a bit more detail regarding the colours which are pretty constant.

Comment: Will the last color always be one or two letters?